# How to populate NULL column with the previous column per group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

How can I populate the `NULL` value with the previous row per group?

Say something like,

```
+--------+---------+--------+
| Date   | Product | Amount |
+        +         +        +
| 7/1/15 | Prod1   | 5      |
| 7/1/15 | Prod2   | 7      |
| 7/1/15 | Prod3   | 9      |
| 8/1/15 | Prod1   | NULL   |
| 8/1/15 | Prod2   | 8      |
| 8/1/15 | Prod3   | NULL   |
| 9/1/15 | Prod1   | 1      |
| 9/1/15 | Prod2   | NULL   |
| 9/1/15 | Prod3   | NULL   |
| 10/1/15| Prod1   | NULL   |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

To achieve something like this:

```
+--------+---------+--------+
| Date   | Product | Amount |
+        +         +        +
| 7/1/15 | Prod1   | 5      |
| 7/1/15 | Prod2   | 7      |
| 7/1/15 | Prod3   | 9      |
| 8/1/15 | Prod1   | 5      |
| 8/1/15 | Prod2   | 8      |
| 8/1/15 | Prod3   | 9      |
| 9/1/15 | Prod1   | 1      |
| 9/1/15 | Prod2   | 8      |
| 9/1/15 | Prod3   | 9      |
| 10/1/15| Prod1   | 1      |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

Does this make sense? I have no idea where to start. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Rule:

- If `Amount` column is `NULL` then it should be populated with the `Amount` of the previous `Amount` in the same `Product` category which in not `NULL`.

Say for example, above is a sample data.

This row

```
Date   | Product | Amount
8/1/15 | Prod1   | NULL
```

It's amount should be populated with `5` since it should get the values prior to it in the same `Product` category.

Comment: _"Does this make sense?"_ No. You havent explained the rules, what means previous? Why do you use 5 for the first null and 9 for the second? The rule doesn't seem to be consistent, is it?

Comment: I have edited my post. Sorry. I think I have confused you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL`(or `COALESCE`) and a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  t.Date, t.Product, 
        Amount = ISNULL(t.Amount, 
                  (SELECT TOP 1 Amount 
                   FROM dbo.TableName t2
                   WHERE t2.Product = t.Product
                   AND t2.Amount IS NOT NULL
                   AND t2.Date <= t.Date
                   ORDER BY t2.Date DESC))
FROM dbo.TableName t
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6b52/3/0)</kbd> with your sample data.

I prefer `ISNULL` over `CAOLESCE` since the latter [will be translated to a `CASE`  that is executed twice](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/). You can read more about the issue [at MS-Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/336002/unnecessarily-bad-performance-for-coalesce-subquery).

Comment: simple solution +1,  i would like to know how performat a Select in a Select is would it be O*2? or more expensiv

Comment: Hi. It worked. But I don't understand why. Think you can explain for reference? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @BoyPasmo: `ISNULL` takes two arguments. If the first is not `NULL` it is taken. Otherwise the second argument is taken. I'm passing a subquery which returns the `Amount` that belongs to the same `Product`, is not `NULL` and comes before this record according to the date, ordered by date.

Comment: @WiiMaxx: you have to look the the execution plan. With proper indexes this is quite efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need a query like this:

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY [Date]) rn
    FROM yourTable)
, tt AS (
    SELECT t1.[Date], t1.Product, t1.Amount, MAX(CASE WHEN t2.Amount IS NOT NULL THEN t2.rn END) AS LastSeq
    FROM t t1
    LEFT JOIN
    t t2 ON t1.Product = t2.Product AND t2.rn <= t1.rn
    GROUP BY t1.[Date], t1.Product, t1.Amount)
SELECT tt.[Date], tt.Product, ISNULL(tt.Amount, t.Amount) As Amount
FROM tt 
JOIN t ON tt.Product = t.Product AND tt.LastSeq = t.rn  
ORDER BY tt.[Date], tt.Product
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest `cross apply`:

```
update table t cross apply
       (select top 1 t2.*
        from table t2
        where t2.product = t.product and
              t2.date < t.date and
              t2.amount is not null
        order by t2.date desc
       ) toupdate
    set amount = toupdate.amount
    where t.amount is null;
```

EDIT:

If you know that there are never too many strings of `NULL`s, you can do something like:

```
update table t
     set product = coalesce(lag(amount) over (partition by product order by date),
                            lag(amount, 2) over (partition by product order by date),
                            lag(amount, 3) over (partition by product order by date)
                           )
     where product is null;
```

Or, alternatively, just run:

```
update table t
     set product = lag(amount) over (partition by product order by date)
     where product is null;
```

until no rows change.